# SQL MErge statement keeps saying primary key violated

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created the following tables.

```
CREATE TABLE FROOMSERVICEDATA 
(  
  TimeID Number(5) REFERENCES FTimePeriod(TimeID) NOT NULL, 
  RoomID Number(5) REFERENCES FRoom(RoomID) NOT NULL,  
  RoomType_ID Number(5) REFERENCES FROOMTYPE(RoomTypeID) NOT NULL,
  RoomServiceRevenueGenerated Number(10,2) NOT NULL, 
  TotalOrders Number(10,2) NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT RoomServiceDataIDPK  PRIMARY KEY (TimeID, RoomType_ID, RoomID)  
);


CREATE TABLE FTIMEPERIOD 
(  
  TimeID Number(5),
  CalendarDate  DATE,
  CONSTRAINT ftimeperiodid  PRIMARY KEY (TimeID)  
);
```

And a few others that are not too important

I also created the following view to work with

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW RoomServiceInsertView AS
SELECT s.request_id, s.bill_amount, s.request_date, r.ROOM_ID, tp.TimeID, r.ROOM_TYPE_ID
   FROM room_service_request s, room r, ftimeperiod tp
   WHERE   (r.room_id = s.room_id) AND (s.request_date = tp.CALENDARDATE);
   SELECT * FROM RoomServiceInsertView;
```

Now i am attempting to run the following merge statement.

```
    MERGE INTO froomservicedata rsd
    USING (SELECt * FROM RoomServiceView) rsr
    ON ((rsr.ROOM_TYPE_ID = rsd.ROOMTYPE_ID) AND (rsd.TimeID = rsr.TimeID) AND (rsr.ROOM_ID  =  rsd.ROOMID ))
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET 
        rsd.ROOMSERVICEREVENUEGENERATED = rsd.ROOMSERVICEREVENUEGENERATED + rsr.bill_amount,
        rsd.TOTALORDERS= rsd.TOTALORDERS +1
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT VALUES(rsr.TimeID, 
                      rsr.ROOM_ID, 
                      rsr.ROOM_TYPE_ID,
                      rsr.bill_amount
                      ,1);
```

But i am being told that the RoomServiceDataIDPK  Primary key constraint is being broken but shouldn't my merge statement pprevent this from occuring. If the timeID, roomId and roomtypeID of a record match then it should be updated if i am not mistaken but i think it is trying to insert and thus breaking the constraint. Any advice on why this may be happening?

Comment: Try to use error_logging_clause. Doc in https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F

Comment: Try to specify columns explicitly in the INSERT clause.

Comment: The view you have created and the view that is used in merge statement are different. Can you please give query of the view that is used in merge statement?

Comment: Please **edit your question** and include data for all tables involved which will cause the error you describe to occur. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have data in `RoomServiceView` that violates the primary key on `FROOMSERVICEDATA`.

I expect that attempting to add the same primary key

```
 CONSTRAINT RoomServiceDataIDPK  PRIMARY KEY (TimeID, RoomType_ID, RoomID)
```

to `RoomServiceView` will help you figure out the problematic data.

Answer (score 1):

Your view RoomServiceDataIDPK has the same values for (TimeID, RoomType_ID, RoomID) in more than one row.

If that same combination were already in froomservicedata, you would get the exception
"ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source".

Since the combination is **not** found in froomservicedata, the MERGE tries to insert all those rows into froomservicedata, which is causing the exception
"ORA-00001: unique constraint".

In order to find the duplicates, try this:

```
select * from (
  select r.*,
  count(*) over(partition by ROOM_TYPE_ID, TimeID, ROOM_ID) cnt
  from RoomServiceInsertView r
)
where cnt > 1
order by cnt desc, ROOM_TYPE_ID, TimeID, ROOM_ID;
```

Best regards, Stew Ashton